# How to clone an order from one customer to another in magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders

I need to create a button ("Clone Order") in the admin > orders section to clone a customer's order to other customers.

[image]

By clicking this button, a new page will open where I need to put the customer emails to where these orders will be cloned. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a button and call below code :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
        $fromCustomer = $customer->loadByEmail('fromemail@gmail.com');
        $toCustomer = $customer->loadByEmail('toemail@gmail.com');
        
        $orderEmailCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$fromCustomer->getEmail());
        $orderIdCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$fromCustomer->getId());
        
        foreach($orderEmailCollection as $order){
            $order->setCustomerId($toCustomer->getId());
            $order->setCustomerEmail($toCustomer->getEmail());
            $order->save();
        }
        
        foreach($orderIdCollection as $order){
            $order->setCustomerId($toCustomer->getId());
            $order->setCustomerEmail($toCustomer->getEmail());
            $order->save();
        }
```